# Assign selected value to a variable

Tags: php, mysql

Just like the title says I need to take the selected value from my dropdown box and assign that to a variable.

```
<?php

 $host = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $pass = "";
 $database = "database_camcalc";

 $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($database, $conn);

 $query = "SELECT camera FROM camlist";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

 $dropdown = "<select name='cameraDD' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $dropdown .= "\r\n\<option value='{$row['camera']}'>{$row['camera']}</option>";
 }
 $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
 echo ('<form method="POST">');
 echo ($dropdown);
 echo ('</form>');

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to put it in a form, and submit the form.

You can then use something like:

```
$selected = isset($_POST['cameraDD'])?$_POST['cameraDD']:null;
```

This will hold the value of the selected option that was sent when the form was submitted.

You can have the form autosubmit by changing the select to submit on change:

```
 $dropdown = "<select name='cameraDD' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
```

This will only work if the `<select>` is inside a `<form>` tag.
i.e.:

```
echo('<form method="post">');
echo($dropdown);
echo('</form>');
```

Comment: I edited the code to add what you suggested and I still get an error of undefined index when I try to use `$var = $_POST['cameraDD'];`

Comment: Made a change to check that the post variable exists

Answer (score 1):

`$var = $_POST['cameraDD']` or `$var = $_GET['cameraDD']`.

It depends of `<form method="?"></form>`.

---

For:

```
<form action="POST">
    ...
    <select name="cameraDD">...</select>
    ...
</form>
```

It would be:

```
$var = $_POST['cameraDD'];
```

---

For:

```
<form action="GET">
    ...
    <select name="cameraDD">...</select>
    ...
</form>
```

It would be:

```
$var = $_GET['cameraDD'];
```

---

You may ignore form method by using:

```
$var = $_REQUEST['cameraDD'];
```

But I don't recommend it.

---

To show such form you might use:

```
echo '<form action="POST" action="somepage.php">',
     'something else',
     $dropdown,
     'something else',
     '<input type="submit" value="send">',
     '</form>';
```

You might consider [***forms***](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) and [***templates***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292395/php-templating) for further reading.

Comment: How could I put this in a form while keeping my sql queries intact? Maybe thats what I should've asked to begin with.

Comment: This works great! unfortunately everytime I hit send it resets the dropdown box back to the first value rather than keeping it at what was selected. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
   $var=$_POST['cameraDD'];
```

if form method is post AND,

```
       $var=$_GET['cameraDD']
```

if form method is get;